# Focussing the right window

Tags: delphi, winapi

The scenario is that I have a 'main app' and a 'helper app'. The 'helper app' pops up on a keyboard hook, does it's stuff, then refocuses the main app window. The problem is that if the main app pops up a modal dialog when helper is active, and the helper then refocuses the wrong window, the modal dialog is hidden and the main app appears 'frozen'.

Any suggestions of strategies to solve this?

Comment: Why are you messing with focus like this? What do you mean by pops up on a keyboard hook?

Comment: How are you refocusing the main app window from the helper window?

Comment: The situation is that the popups occur as a result of a barcode scan (hence the keyboard hook). The main application also gets the keyboard (scanner) data and processes it independently. The secondary application is a reminder pop-up that comes on screen for a few seconds then disappears and refocuses main app. However in some cases the main app has displayed a modal error dialog and if we don't focus that, then the form we are focussing can go over the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the modal form of the 'main app' is not owned by the main app window, otherwise the modal form would stay above the main form at all times. So, possibly, either there's no `MainFormOnTaskbar` property for the Delphi version that it was compiled, or it is not set. Then it must be the hidden application window that owns the windows.

You can test if the main app window is disabled when closing your 'helper app' form (that would be the case if there's a modal form), and restore the last active popup window that is owned by the hidden application window if it is.

```
var
  Wnd: HWND;     // handle to 'main app's main form
  mWnd: HWND;    // handle to possible modal form
  AppWnd: HWND;  // handle to hidden Application window
begin
  ..

  if not IsWindowEnabled(Wnd) then begin  // test if there's a modal form
    AppWnd := GetWindowLong(Wnd, GWL_HWNDPARENT); // TApplication window handle
    mWnd := GetLastActivePopup(AppWnd); // most recently active popup window

      // restore focus to mWnd     

  end else
    // restore focus to Wnd
```

(Don't forget to include tests for the result of the API functions of course.)

Comment: That's great thanks. Seems to work well. I read in the GetWindowLong info that it is deprecated for Win64 ... I haven't had much to do with Win64, is this likely to still be ok for this use? My app is Win32 so I presume compatibility exists unless I'm writing a 64 bit program.

Comment: And one more question about this ... is this solution assuming that the main app is a delphi app? I'm aware that the structure of Delphi apps isn't common, with the hidden main window etc. So is this likely to be a fairly generic solution?

Comment: @Terry - You're welcome!. (1) Yes, but when you compile your program with 64bit compiler, you have to use `GetWindowLongPtr` with index `GWLP_HWNDPARENT`. (2) Yes, this solution not only assumes the main app is a Delphi application, but also that it doesn't employ `MainFormOnTaskbar` as stated in the first paragraph. A generic solution would be to activate the main form and leave the rest alone, a possible modal window would not be activated but would stay in front of the main form and the user could see it.

Comment: @Terry - In any case, if you need to, you can device an algorithm to account for both kind of behavior. For instance, when the main form is disabled first see if it has got a last active popup other than itself, activate it if there is, if not see if it has got an owner window (might need to test if this is not the Desktop window) and see if the owner window has got a last active popup other than the main window, etc...

Comment: Thanks very much for your help on this. I'll try as you suggest and search for a lastactivepopup on the window and on its parent. I guess that will be 99% of apps covered and if I don't find the right app it's not the end of the world if I just don't focus anything as it should be an error case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Application.Restore` or `Application.RestoreTopMosts`. And when that modal dialog is shown by a WinAPI call, then also try `Application.Normalize(All)TopMosts` before.

Now, this could be sufficient, but in my own application which hides the application handle from the taskbar, it doesn't and I needed the following routine which is the handler of a `TApplicationEvents.OnActivate` event:

```
procedure TMainForm.AppEventsActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  TopWindow: HWND;
begin
  TopWindow := GetLastActivePopup(Application.Handle);
  if (TopWindow <> 0) and (TopWindow <> Application.Handle) then
  begin
    BringToFront;
    SetForegroundWindow(TopWindow);
  end;
end;
```

Clarification: the code in `Application.BringToFront` is almost the same, but it does not guarantee to also show the main form in the background. I.e. `Application.BringToFront` may show *only* the modal dialog.

Comment: This looks like it's in the right general direction, but I can only change the secondary application. So I need to detect the topmost window of the main app. I know the handle of the window that was displayed when my window popped up, but don't know if there is a modal dialog that the main app has displayed since the popup appeared.