# ShowMessage is hidden

Tags: delphi, windows-xp, delphi-xe3

I'm using Delphi XE3 in a complex application that has MDI forms, and forms that stays on top also.

Sometimes a simple `ShowMessage('...')` does not appear and stays behind the main application window.

Either people think that the application has crashed, or go to task manager and put back the application on top, and then showmessage windows come back on top.

This is occuring in XP, I haven't seen that under Win8 so far.

Any idea why?

Comment: Strange, our company started having this problem as of Vista+, but was fine on XP... Is XP up to date?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi - how do I find out which modal dialog has focus and bring it to the front?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811940/delphi-how-do-i-find-out-which-modal-dialog-has-focus-and-bring-it-to-the-fron)

Comment: See also: [Focussing the right window](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8529946/757830)

Comment: With a showmessage, things are limited...

Comment: Create a simple reproduction that we can examine. Otherwise you'll get lots of guesses and advice to do wacky things. As for general advice, stop using stay on top and just set the window owner, aka popup parent, correctly.

Comment: There is no way to put a code that reproduces that... or I haven't found it. To me it looks random...
But I have the feeling it depends on the last window that has the focus.

Comment: `Application.NormalizeTopMosts;` would not solve the problem?

Comment: @Matheus - I don't think so. ShowMessage already leads to NormalizeAllTopMosts. With XE2 anyway.

Comment: Indeed I have noticed that the hidden showmessage comes after  MDIchild that is focused, with bstoolwindow set
popupmode is set to pmnone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Wrote your own myShowMSG function. In this function wrote the simple custom message form and some code to control - "Are this form are visible to user?" In control code write to error.log all tracelog information about this problem. Include the list of actually created forms and their states to .log
2. Replace all ShowMessage in your project to myShowMSG
3. Run all tests
4. Read your error.log's. Post it here to disquss